# concatenation of global.getelementbyid into single variable

Tags: javascript

Can I concatenate 3 `global.getElementById` statement into a single variable.these are some codes..

```
var cmbOrgNodeType = global.getElementById('cmbOrgNodeType').options[global.getElementById('cmbOrgNodeType').selectedIndex].value;    
var cmbOrgNodeSubType = global.getElementById('cmbOrgNodeSubType').options[global.getElementById('cmbOrgNodeSubType').selectedIndex].value;    
var cmbOrgNodeComponentType = global.getElementById('cmbOrgNodeComponentType').options[global.getElementById('cmbOrgNodeComponentType').selectedIndex].value;
```

I want to concatenate these three into single variable var `TypeID=?`
what should i do to store the value of all these three in single variable.?

Answer (score 0):

To create a concatenated string of all values:

```
var TypeID = cmbOrgNodeType + cmbOrgNodeSubType + cmbOrgNodeComponentType;
```

Unless you still need to access the individually, I'd do this:

```
TypeID = { 
  cmbOrgNodeType: null, 
  cmbOrgNodeSubType: null, 
  cmbOrgNodeComponentType: null 
}
for(name in TypeID) {
  TypeID[name] = global.getElementById(name).options[global.getElementById(name).selectedIndex].value;
}
```

Remember that it's nice to be **DRY** :)

Answer (score 0):

As in store them together?

```
var nodes = {
 cmbOrgNodeType: global.getElementById('cmbOrgNodeType').options[global.getElementById('cmbOrgNodeType').selectedIndex].value,
 cmbOrgNodeSubType: global.getElementById('cmbOrgNodeSubType').options[global.getElementById('cmbOrgNodeSubType').selectedIndex].value,
 cmbOrgNodeComponentType: global.getElementById('cmbOrgNodeComponentType').options[global.getElementById('cmbOrgNodeComponentType').selectedIndex].value
}

alert(nodes.cmbOrgNodeType)
alert(nodes.cmbOrgNodeSubType)
alert(nodes.cmbOrgNodeComponentType)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by creating an object in javascript like this.

```
var TypeID={}
TypeID.cmbOrgNodeType =cmbOrgNodeType ;
TypeID.cmbOrgNodeSubType =cmbOrgNodeSubType ;
TypeID.cmbOrgNodeComponentType =cmbOrgNodeComponentType ;
```

You can access it like this if you want.

```
 TypeID.cmbOrgNodeType
 TypeID.cmbOrgNodeSubType 
 TypeID.cmbOrgNodeComponentType
```

Answer (score 0):

You could literally concatenate the strings:

```
var type = cmbOrgNodeType + " " + cmbOrgNodeSubType + " " + cmbOrgNodeComponentType;
```

However, this would be difficult to extract their old values from, so unless you're outputting it, I would recommend that you store them in an object, so that it can be used as one variable:

```
var type = {
    "cmbOrgNodeType": global.getElementById('cmbOrgNodeType').options[global.getElementById('cmbOrgNodeType').selectedIndex].value,
    "cmbOrgNodeSubType": global.getElementById('cmbOrgNodeSubType').options[global.getElementById('cmbOrgNodeSubType').selectedIndex].value,
    "cmbOrgNodeComponentType": global.getElementById('cmbOrgNodeComponentType').options[global.getElementById('cmbOrgNodeComponentType').selectedIndex].value
}
```

(this is [object-literal notation](http://www.dyn-web.com/tutorials/obj_lit.php))

Then you can access each property using `type.cmbOrgNodeType`, etc.